# Python string template substitution with dict of regex groups?

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I'm new to python/programing in general and trying to build a statsd to opentsdb proxy based off prometheus' statsd proxy in go. 
I'm trying to have a string template like the following:

```
label_name = "${1}_${2}_${3}_${6}"
```

Then using the above label = string template format, replace the contents of 1,2,3, and 7 with the re.match.groups of a different string. I thought I could do this with strings Template.safe_substitute and a small for loop to turn the groups into a dictionary:

```
     ...:         label_match_dict = {}
     ...:         for i in range(len(input_match.groups())):
     ...:             label_match_dict[str(i+1)] = input_match.groups()[i]
```

Yet I am having trouble because it looks like string.Template() is looking for `[_a-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]` which will not match my dict of `{1: "blue", 2: "green", 3: "red", 4: "yellow"}`. Now I'm completely lost and feel like there must be a clean way to do this instead of my garden path.

So say I have a statsd metric like:

```
connstats_by.vip.nested._Common_Domain.89.44.250.117.conncount:40|g
```

and a regex string like [so](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6ImNvbm5zdGF0c19ieVxcLnZpcFxcLm5lc3RlZFxcLihbXi5dKilcXC4oW14uXSopXFwuKFteLl0qKVxcLihbXi5dKilcXC4oW14uXSopXFwuKFteXFw6XSopKD86XFw6KShbXlxcfF0qKSg%2FOlxcfCkoW15cXG5dKikiLCJmbGFncyI6MCwibWF0Y2hfdHlwZSI6Im1hdGNoIiwidGVzdF9zdHJpbmciOiJjb25uc3RhdHNfYnkudmlwLm5lc3RlZC5fQ29tbW9uX0RvbWFpbi4xOTIuMTY4LjEuMTE3LmNvbm5jb3VudDo0MHxnIn0%3D):

```
re.compile('connstats_by\\.vip\\.nested\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^\:]*)(?:\:)([^\|]*)(?:\|)([^\n]*)')
```

Which after the above for loop gives me:

```
{ 1: "_Primary_Domain",
  2: "192",
  3: "168",
  4: "1",
  5: "117",
  6: "conncount",
  7: "40",
  8: "g" }
```

I just can't seem to wrap my brain around substituting the members of the template with the members of the dict without a really gross looking nested for loop. I feel like I am going down the wrong path. I am hoping someone here can point me toward a more pythonic direction that I can understand 3 months down the road.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what exactly is your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string wants a positional list, so this should work:

```
label_name = "${1}_${2}_${3}_${6}"
metric = "connstats_by.vip.nested._Common_Domain.89.44.250.117.conncount:40|g"
rx = re.compile('connstats_by\\.vip\\.nested\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^.]*)\\.([^\:]*)(?:\:)([^\|]*)(?:\|)([^\n]*)')
print(label_name.format(*rx.match(metric).groups()))
```

Which prints

```
$89_$44_$250_$40
```

Comment: Oh snap! Thank you so much that's so much simpler than me doing 3 regex substitutions. Now I just need to remove the dollar sign which is nothing. Thank you so much!